# HTTParty not removing HTML special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, httparty

When I make the request for "Mocha" through HTTParty with the following code

```
class Recipe
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "http://www.food2fork.com/api"
  default_params key: key_value
  format :json
  def self.for(ingredient)
    get('/search', {query: {q: ingredient}})["recipes"]
  end
end
```

in the responses I get `"Kahl&uacute;a-Spiked"` instead of `"Kahlúa-Spiked"`. How do I re-encode the first to get the second? What's going wrong here?

EDIT:
It appears to be an issue with JSON in ruby not decoding the strings. HTTParty uses the native json package to parse and it seems to not be working.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [HTMLEntities](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlentities):

```
require 'htmlentities'
HtmlEntities.new.decode("Kahl&uacute;a-Spiked") # "Kahlúa-Spiked"
```

Comment: I'll try that. This is for a MOOC, so it may not work on their grader

Comment: The way to do this was by using sanitize on the text outputs.